# Is Gorm Preload function a good practice in terms of performance?

Tags: go, eager-loading, go-gorm

Why Preload function in Gorm is a “good practice” since it retrieves all the records of a given table (eager loading) every time it is called?

I saw a lot of people referencing the Preload as a good solution when working with relations and I don’t understand why.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are talking about;

but generally; the computational cost is different for joins / vs lookups.

given two tables: kake and topping:

kake (name str)
topping (name str)

if you join, you will have a much larger set (disk input-output, memory) than in if you do matches;

because you need to calculate ALL PERMUTATIONS.

### table snapshot

cake:

```
1|napoleon
2|chocolate
3|cheese
```

topping:

```
1|butter
2|frosting
3|cacao
4|white cacao
5|goat chese
6|cow chese
7|chinese chese
...|nuts
...|avocado
...|white chocolate
11:cherry-flavor
```

### query logic

with a general join you will have results 3 x 11 - all cakes times all toppings.

this may seem trivial, but it is not when the tables have 1000+ records.

with "preload" you will have;

```
get all topings for napoleon => only frosting
get all topings for chocolate  => only cacao
get all toppings for cheese => only cow chese and only chinise chese
```

then; given my napoleon + chocolate + cheese,

you can avoid: butter, cherry flavor

so you select only the relevant related records.

this is not simple.
it causes other problems.
but generally, performance is better if you can say:

I need all x,y,z and never a,b,c.

I hope this makes sense.